# Interactive HTML table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a SQL Table with 10 columns (One is ID, with AI).
I have 9 input fields to fill my SQL table.
I have an HTML table to display only 5 columns from my SQL table (which has 10 columns).
I also have buttons that are "Input new", "Update", "Delete", "Save", "Cancel"

When I click on an HTML table row I want to display data from SQL table row, into my input fields, so I can update my SQL table and my HTML table, using the same input fields that I use to input new data in a SQL table.

I am not looking for you to write my code, just to point me in the right direction where to look for a solution. I have searched, but without any results, perhaps I have been looking in the wrong places or with using the wrong terms.

Comment: Search "CRUD operations in PHP" on youtube, you can see bunch of tutorials

Comment: But the main question is how to integrate them with an interactable HTML table, I know how to update, delete, post new data into SQL table, I just don't know how to make it interact with HTML table.

Comment: For this you need AJAX, use js to check onclick on row, then make php script. fetch data using ajax by calling the php script and set value of input tag

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into it.

Comment: If you're looking at the front end you'll need to consider something with JS that will make the table cells editable on a `click` of a row and then as stated above consider whether you want to update that once the user clicks away from the row with AJAX or whether the user then submits the form. There's plenty of library's including VUE or jQuery that will help you or plain vanilla JS. All depends on your use case on how simple or complex you want to make it

Comment: I don't want the HTML table to be editable, it is there just to show the data from the SQL table, and to fill in the form with the click on the HTML table row. And from the form I do updates. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer I will look into it.